# Extending Cylinder with Threading?

Tags: modeling

I have a cylinder with a thread pattern in the middle, and I am trying to extend it. I tried using the boolean modifier on the middle section and was able to use the array modifier to extend it but it didn't merge. Even though the pattern matched the vertexes are at different positions.

[image]

Comment: can u pls provide blend file? thx

Comment: @Chris Here's the file: https://easyupload.io/v7jr8x

Comment: ok, unfortunately you already applied your modifiers...i hoped you didn't.  do you have a version with non-applied modifiers?

Comment: No I don't have the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your tris to quads with an <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>, simplify the mesh:

[image]

Hide the cylinder, use the *Knife* to cut a segment (<kbd>K</kbd> to activate, <kbd>A</kbd> to cut perpendicularly, <kbd>C</kbd> to cut through), and press <kbd>V</kbd> to rip right away:

[image]

Remove the other parts:

[image]

Unhide the cylinder and align it with the segment with the *Snap* (*to Vertex*) option:

[image]

Right click > *Shade Smooth*, in the *Object Data* panel click on *Clear Custom Clear Split Normals Data*, and *Auto Smooth* :

[image]

Apply the *Rotation* and *Scale* of your object, give it an *Array* modifier on Y, enable the *Merge* option :

[image]

You’ll need to correct the topology to make the vertices of the instances stick to each other:

[image]